# What to do if you stop to believe in Allah?

Tags: punishment, imaan, atheism

Should you continue to live your life as false Muslim or you should confront your family and friends and confess your situation?

What does Quran say about that situation? What are the proscribed punishments if any?

Comment: Please do not treat this as a provocation. This is a valid question and infact I have a friend in this situation, so I genuinely want to know the official position on this matter.

Comment: Does anyone knows any material from the scripture which addresses this situation? Also, there is a following problem - you either tell the truth about your atheism to your family or you lie to them because you don't want to argue with them. I suppose that lying is also a sin in Islam, so how do you proceed?

Comment: @kolja I don't understand. If one is not Muslim and does not believe in the scripture, then why does he need to bother that lying is a sin in Islam?

Comment: Hello kolja, You aksed 3 questions. I would suggest that you edit your question and remove 2 of the questions and ask them separately so that it is easier for us to answer your questions :-)

Comment: @mezhang, I've answered your comment bellow Kaveh's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam,

Hi kolja, I'll try to answer your question with surah [Al-Munafiqun](http://quran.com/63) (The Hypocrites) below,

> ```
>  When the hypocrites come to you, [O Muhammad], they say, "We
> testify that you are the Messenger of Allah ." And Allah knows that
> you are His Messenger, and Allah testifies that the hypocrites are
> liars. (QS. Al-Munafiqun: 1)
> ```
>
> ```
>  They have taken their oaths as a cover, so they averted [people]
> from the way of Allah. Indeed, it was evil that they were doing. (QS.
> Al-Munafiqun: 2)
> ```
>
> ```
>  That is because they believed, and then they disbelieved; so
> their hearts were sealed over, and they do not understand. (QS.
> Al-Munafiqun: 3)
> ```

the verses say that someone in your question which you declared as `Muslims stop being believers` are called `the Hypocrites`

As your main question is

> Should I continue to live my life as false Muslim or I should
>   confront my family and friends and confess my situation

I'd like to called it as **The Hypocrite** rather than `people of other religions or atheists`

Another part of your question about 
`What does Quran say about that situation?`
and
`What are the proscribed punishments if any?`

I will answer it based on surah Al-Munafiqun verse 5 and 6

> ```
> And when it is said to them, "Come, the Messenger of Allah will
> ask forgiveness for you," they turn their heads aside and you see them
> evading while they are arrogant. (QS. Al-Munafiqun: 5)
> ```

The situation is have been happened in Rasulullah era, they are arrogant, the one who called The Hypocrite in this case is Abdullah bin Ubay bin Salul (that was I learnt in my childhood). But this condition can applied to other people.

> ```
> It is all the same for them whether you ask forgiveness for them
> or do not ask forgiveness for them; never will Allah forgive them.
> Indeed, Allah does not guide the defiantly disobedient people. (QS.
> Al-Munafiqun: 6)
> ```

based on verse 6, it's hopeless to you if you ask forgiveness for them since as you say, maybe they will `confront his family and friends and confess his situation`.

Why he will do that?? **because The Hypocrites are arrogant.**

Hope helps.

Salam, 
Ahmad

Comment: Salaam. I don't think this particular case can be generalized. It seems that Quran uses "hypocrites" for people who claim to be believers publicly while they are not. In this cases we are talking about people who publicly say they don't believe.

Comment: Wa'alaikum salam. Thanks for explanation. if OP question are about people who publicity say they don't believe, I agree with your answer. ^^. may be I just misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Reading the question again, I can see that your interpretation can also be correct as it seems the person has not revealed to their family that they do not believe.

Comment: maybe we need OP to clarify first.. since both of us are true. ^^

Comment: @Ahmad First off, thank you for the answer. Let me clarify - I wanted to know whats's worse IN YOUR VIEW - to hide that one lost belief in God or to hide it from the family? Also, I do not understand why being a hypocrite automatically makes one arrogant.

Comment: nothing worse for me, it's just but decision for the doer. The Hypocrite is arrogant because God called him like that. But if you asked my view about him, I'll related it with Abdullah bin Ubay bin Salul's story. Before prophet Muhammad came to Madinah, he is the one who will be candidate to be a leader in Madinah, sort of that, he can't when Rasulullah became a leader in Madinah. if you see [QS. Al-Munafiqun verse 7](http://quran.com/63/7) and [verse 8](http://quran.com/63/8), he say the words that will known till the end of days, you will knew it, how they are arrogant. ^^. Hope helps.

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>[[Al-Hujurat 14](http://quran.com/49/14)]</sup> *The bedouins say, "We believe." Say [to them], "You have not believed; rather say 'We have submitted [in Islam],' for faith has not yet entered your hearts. And if you obey Allah and His Messenger, He will not deprive you from your deeds of anything. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful."*

Islam is, fundamentally, submission to God's laws and His authority.  In the [hadith of Jibril](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1250630), a clear distinction is made between "Islam" and "Iman"; whereas Iman is about belief in God and the unseen and all that entails, Islam is only defined in relation to its outward actions (e.g. fasting, salat, zakat).

The hypocrites are those who claim to be Muslims while rejecting God's authority, those who (for example) only perform the duties of Islam when they are seen by others, but abandon them — or even work *against* Islam — when they are alone.  The apostates, on the other hand, are those who once claimed to be Muslim, but no longer follow, nor claim to follow, God's law at all.

However, just because one lacks *iman* does not necessarily make one a "false Muslim."  One can be weak in faith — so weak as to be practically non-existant — without actually *rejecting* God's authority; as long as he continues to obey God's commandments, in private as well as in public, he is still Muslim (at least so far as worldly punishments are concerned).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you saying that if a person obeys all laws of islam and lives fully in accordance to Quran, it does not matter if he actually believe in Allah or not?

Comment: @kolja pretty much.  Iman (faith/belief) is considered by many scholars to be a higher (and more difficult) grade of Islam to achieve.

Comment: I did not expect this kind of answer. Interesting. Any citations from the Quran?

Comment: @kolja The whole first quote is a citation from the Qur'an.  What more do you want?

Comment: @goldPseudo : _Iman (faith/belief) is considered by many scholars to be a higher (and more difficult) grade of Islam to achieve._ --- who are those "many scholars" and where they have mentioned that?

Comment: @shoerat don't have direct references handy.  pretty sure it's mentioned in Ibn Kathir though.

Answer (score 0):

If a person stops believing in Islam then he is free to follow it as a  culture or as if he is the citizen of the "nation" of Islam without following its laws. Many citizens of a country don't believe in the laws of that country and are anti govt that does not stop them from being the citizen of the country. It is foolish for the citizen of a country to go around and publicize that he does not want citizenship and speak ill of the nation, this would only invite trouble and harassment to the person. Moreover if one  person  thinks like that then the there are 1000+ others who love their nation and would like the one who has disbelieved to remain in the fold of Islam , in hope that in the future  even if he does not believe , his progeny would believe as they are more closer to Islam than people of other religion\ Atheists. So yes a person who does not believe in Allah (Atheist) can remain to be a part of Islam. It  is the most practical thing for such people to remain in the fold of Islam and probably  your friend has also realized this.

I assume that your friend is young, it is very common in non Muslim countries to have atheist Muslim youths, a significant chunk of them are expected to transition as normal Islamic believers as and when they understand their religion, and this too is very common.

Comment: somebody deleted my comment here. why would you do that? I said to @Ali that his analogy was flawed - if you do not agree with the laws of your country, you can change them through political activity, not possible within Islam.

Comment: @kolja thanks for the feedback, maybe your past comment was not even saved(it has happened to me many a times), anyways reg changing laws then one person or even a fringe group cant change the nation directly on short notice, e.g: there is this 99% movement in USA , even these 99% Americans could not move the 1% in power. So the avg american does what is obvious , i.e live with the system being a part of it.

Answer (score -1):

A person born is a muslim family is a muslim by birth. There comes a time (usually) when he accepts (or rejects) is willingly. This happens when he comes of age and has an inclination to think in this direction.

Allah has made this world on a rule that we will be tested in this world and the result will be announced in the next world. What good is a test if you get punishment at the first wrong doing, or rewarded at the first good deed. So you a free to choose whether you think that Islam is the right religion or not, or God exists or not.

Allah has not only given his introduction though prophets but first though inspiration to every single human being in his subconsciousness. If you remain true to yourself, you will eventually find that there is a God and you will meet him someday.

You can choose to proclaim it or keep it hidden. It does not matter to Allah, he knows it and he will judge you accordingly.