# If a person left Islam

Tags: sharia

I am here put a simple question about Islam. If a person born Muslim or newly Muslim and he left Islam in the following situations

1. Respect Messenger Prophet Muhammad and Qua-ran but not satisfied Muslim's behaviour or Islamic way of life.
2. Person say my previous religion is good, so I go back with giving any respect or insult to Islam.
3. Do not respect Prophet Muhammad and Qua-ran and join other religion.
4. Left Islam and say I have no religion now.

So what Qua-ran and Sunnah say's about such person belong to any category?

Comment: I would like to direct you to one of my questions that has relevant and interesting answers: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8864/what-to-do-if-you-stop-to-believe-in-allah

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a vague [What does Islam say about X?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/what-does-islam-say-about-x) question.  (There's lots of material about apostates; what precisely do you want to know?  All of it?)

Answer (score -1):

The situations can be separated in in two part:

- He/She find an other religion which is really better than Islam
- He/She is too lazy to be a Muslim and he/she do not want to be a Muslim

If the person believe in after world and care for it, so the second reason is unacceptable and there will be no excuse for being lazy.

But if he/she really find an other religion by researching deep all of them and judging them fairly it's OK and allowed. But remember the god himself said that the best and the final religion is Islam.

Comment: `researching deep all of them and judging them fairly it's OK and allowed`, how is it allowed. I dare say, not allowed.

Comment: @Aref can you give authentic references to your answer.